# Is it possible to encrypt / decrypt a Sequelize model's field with a unique validation?

Tags: express, encryption, sequelize.js, unique

for the GDPR I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt my user's personal data from my Sequelize Users model. My username and email fields must be unique.

I tried to use the afterValidate and the beforeValidate hooks, but on validation, Sequelize can't recognize if the fields are unique or not because they already are encrypted, and a crypt is always different.

How do you handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using random initVector and Securitykey,which will be different in different times. So you have to use a const value which can be saved in a config file.
Ex :

```
initVectorString: 'xx567876567898765',
  securitykeyString:
    'Zzzz345678909876545678984567890',
```

After saving in the config file, you can have a encrypt and decrypt function as follows

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc';
const initVector = Buffer.from(initVectorString, 'hex');
const Securitykey = Buffer.from(securitykeyString, 'hex');

function encryptData(data) {
  try {
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, Securitykey, initVector);
    let encryptedData = cipher.update(data, 'utf-8', 'hex');
    encryptedData += cipher.final('hex');

    return encryptedData;
  } catch (error) {}
}


function decryptData(data) {
  try {
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(
      algorithm,
      Securitykey,
      initVector
    );
    let decryptedData = decipher.update(data, 'hex', 'utf-8');
    decryptedData += decipher.final('utf8');

    return decryptedData;
  } catch (error) {}
}
```